# Pandas highlight specific number with different color in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to highlight specific number with different color in my dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))
```

I can highlight a specific number by one color, for example:

```
def HIGHLIGHT_COLOR(x):
criteria = x == 4
return ['background-color: green' if i else '' for i in criteria]

df.style.apply(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
```

What I need is to highlight every individual number, here's my code but it doesn't work:

```
def HIGHLIGHT_COLOR(x):
    if x == 4:
        color = green
    elif x == 2:
        color = yellow
    elif x == 3:
        color = grey
    elif x == 7: 
        color = purple
    elif x == 10:
        color = black
    return f'color: {color}'

df.style.apply(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
```

Can anyone assist this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adjusting your function here is my solution:

```
def HIGHLIGHT_COLOR(x):
    def colour_switch(number):
        if number == 4:
            color = "green"
        elif number == 2:
            color = "yellow"
        elif number == 3:
            color = "grey"
        elif number == 7: 
            color = "purple"
        elif number == 10:
            color = "black"
        else:
            # default
            color = "white"
            
        return color

    return [f'background-color: {colour_switch(number)}' for number in x]

df.style.apply(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

An option with [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [Series.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
def HIGHLIGHT_COLOR(x):
    return ('background-color: ' + x.map({
        4: 'green',
        2: 'yellow',
        3: 'grey',
        7: 'purple',
        10: 'black'
    })).fillna('')


df.style.apply(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
```

[image: styled]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by:

```
def HIGHLIGHT_COLOR(inp):
    colors = []
    for x in inp:
        if x == 4:
            colors.append('green')
        elif x == 2:
            colors.append('yellow')
        elif x == 3:
            colors.append('grey')
        elif x == 7: 
            colors.append('purple')
        elif x == 10:
            colors.append('black')
    return [f'background-color: {color}' for color in colors]

df.style.apply(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was what I meant. However, your code doesn't work either. Anything missed?

Comment: Due to an error code, I had to add colors=[] in front of for loop. However, it still is not working properly. Thank you though!

Comment: It shows "Function <function HIGHLIGHT_COLOR at 0x00000226ABC86F70> returned the wrong shape. Result has shape: (3,) Expected shape:   (3, 3)"